# Mule:Dataweave Iteration not working

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to take output from Salesforce & transform it to a json. here is my code:

```
  %dw 1.0
  %output application/json 

  payload map {
             headerandlines:{  id           : $.Id,
               agreementLineID     : $.LineItems__r.Id,
               netPrice            : $.LineItems__r.Price__c,
               volume              : $.Volume__c,
               name                : $.Name,
               StartDate           : $.Start_Date__c,
               EndDate             : $.End_Date__c,
               poField             : $.PO_Field__c,
               ConsoleNumber        : $.Console_Number__c,
               Term               : $.Term__c,
               ownerID              : $.OwnerId,
                Unit               : $.Unit__c, 
               siteNumber          : $.Site_Num__c,
               customerNumber      : $.Customer_Num__c
             }  


         }
```

input payload looks like this.. it is a collection of objects. Somehow after the transformation only the first object is sent & rest is clobbered.

```
   [
   {
"id": "DA0YAAW",
"LineID": [
  "jGEAU",
  "jBEAU",
  "j6EAE"
],
"Price": [
  "50000.0",
  "12000.0",
  "45000.0"
],
"netPrice": null,
"volume": null,
"name": " Test 2.24",
"StartDate": "2017-02-17",
"EndDate": "2018-02-17",
"poField": "123456",
"ConsoleNumber": "8888888",
"PaymentTerm": "thirty (30)",
"ownerID": “abcd”,
"OperatingUnit": " International Company",
"siteNumber": null,
"customerNumber": null
},
{
"id": "a37n0000000DAMAAA4",
"LineID": [
  "JunEAE",
  "JuiEAE",
  "KdMEAU",
  "JuYEAU"
],
"Price": [
  "5000.0",
  "8000.0",
  "5000.0",
  "5000.0"
],
"netPrice": null,
"volume": null,
"name": " Test 3.6",
"StartDate": "2017-03-06",
"EndDate": "2018-03-16",
"poField": "12345",
"ConsoleNumber": "123456-",
"PaymentTerm": "30 NET",
"ownerID": “dfgh”,
"OperatingUnit": ", inc.",
"siteNumber": null,
"customerNumber": null
},
```

….

]

When I call this code from the browser (using API testing) I get the complete payload with multiple objects. When I call this from another API I get only one 1 object indicating it is not looping through. I can confirm that the payload has multiple objects . Is there anything I am missing in terms of looping through this code to extract multiple objects? I assume that '$' notation is good enough for iteration.

Comment: what does payload look like?

Comment: Hi added the input payload

Comment: u serious? your example is full of invalid characters and it does not contain a single attribute referenced in your dataweave.

Comment: well I showed you the json format of the object as the object is quite cluttered. I can share the object details as well.

Answer (score 0):

@insaneyogi, your input is either incorrect or your dataweave is incorrect.
Here in the input you have specified id in the small. but in dataweave, it is mentioned in capital.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with your Lineitem and Price type elements. They are collection within and element. In your data mapping $. will take care of the outer object. However,  i think the mapping like LineItems__r.Price__c is not correct. It should have proper index , probably  LineItems__r.Price__c[0]. Please try that and it should work. First change the input with single element for price or line-item and test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the agreementLineID and netPrice are arrays and you need to loop through them with a map operator within the bigger outer map to get all the line items. That should work.